# When will read on a blocking and non-blocking socket return zero?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I know that read on a socket will return 0 when the connection has been shutdown. But is this true for both blocking and non-blocking sockets?

Comment: Why not ... try it and find out?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any statement in the documentation to the contrary, it must be presumed true. Why do you think the blocking mode would make any difference?